# Get collection "backwards" with limit

Tags: mongoose

Okay, let's say I have the following data collection:

"Numbers"

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

But when I load my webpage I only load

```
5 6 7 8 9 10
```

When I scroll up on the web page, I want to load

```
1 2 3 4
```

as well.

I'm trying to do some sort of a "reverse skip" in Mongoose, where I get everything "above" a certain element.

Comment: If *Everything above a certain element* is your criteria then, `Model.find({"_id":{$lt:elementId}})`, could solve your problem, where `_id` is stored as `Numbers`, or do you want to do a pagination with fixed/ configurable number of records per page?